# What is the oscillation of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Define the oscillation of a function at a point $x$ to be (for an open interval $I$):

$$\omega_f(x)=\inf_{x\in I}\sup_{s,t\in I}|f(t)-f(s)|$$

I am a bit confused about the definition above. How am I supposed to interpret the infimum of the supremum of something? The smallest maximum distance between two function values? If I have the maximum distance between two function values, what is there to choose an infimum for? Can someone please clarify?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $I$? (Not a philosophical question.)

Comment: An open interval

Comment: Where did you take that definition from? That $\;x\;$ in the left side doesn't play any role in the right one! Perhaps that's the definition of oscillation of the function *in the whole interval* ?

Comment: You are missing something. Usually it is something line $\operatorname{osc}_f(x) = \inf_{\epsilon>0} \sup_{s,t \in B(x,\epsilon)} |f(t)-f(s)|$.

Comment: @Timbuc the infimum is over all $I$ *containing $x$*

Comment: @Um That's what I'd think yet it is **not** what the OP wrote.

Comment: In my book, *Real Analysis* by N.L. Carothers, he uses the following definition exactly: $\omega_f(x)=\inf_{x\ni I}\sup_{s,t\in I}|f(t)-f(s)|$. Perhaps I misunderstood what $x\ni I$ means.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan First, it seems it should be $\;x\in I\;$ and **not** $\;x\ni I\;$ . Second, the infimum seems to be taken, as Umberto says, over all open subintervals $\;I\;$ containing $\;x\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc perhaps $\displaystyle \inf_{I \ni x}$ reads better? But to me the meaning of the expression as written is clear. This infimum is over a set of intervals.

Comment: @UmbertoP. That'd make sense, yet I'd rather have it as $\;x\in I\;$ and not as $\;I\ni x\;$ .

Comment: It is crappy notation.

Comment: @UmbertoP. That's exactly what I said you implied: the infimum over all intervals containing $\;x\;$ .

Comment: Show Carother's definition is the same as the one I gave above. I think the one above is a little clearer.

Comment: I think copper's definition is dead clear, and in the real line it is just a (punctured or not) open interval around $\;x\;$ .

Comment: I just checked directly in Carothers' book. It is defined **exactly** as$$\omega_a(f):=\inf_{\begin{align}I\ni a\\I\,\text{open}\end{align}}\omega (f;I)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\omega(f\,;\,(a-h\,,\,a+h))$$ The rightmost limit is just copper's definition written in another form , and $\;\omega (f;I)\;$ is just the oscillation of the function in $\;I\;$ , as mentioned before by Umberto. The central expression is, as flocklorically put by copper, is a pretty crappy one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a point $x$.

Let $I$ be an open interval containing $x$.  The oscillation of $f$ on $I$ is the quantity $\displaystyle \sup_{s,t \in I} |f(t) - f(s)|$.

For all such $I$ containing $x$ you get a value for the oscillation of $f$ on $I$. The oscillation of $f$ at the point $x$ is the infimum of all such values.

Comment: After all the above mess, I think this explains things clear and correctly. +1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The comments above and this answer have helped me understand.

Comment: Umberto P.  writes " The oscillation of $f$ at the point $x$ is the infimum of all such values."  Should I understand that you are referring to the particular interval that is more a less a less a differential around $x$?